# Hide Recent App system Dialog

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

I am closing the recent app dialog by overriding the following method in activity:

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);  
if(!hasFocus) {
Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
}
}
```

But the issue which I am facing is this method is not called if `AlertDialog` is currently visible on the activity. I am not getting call back on `onWindowFocusChanged()` or any other method of Activity life cycle on pressing Recent app button if `AlertDialog` is visible on activity.
Is there any way to catch event of Recent App button or any other way to block or disable Recent app button

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can call this method from `onResume(){...}` of your activity.

Comment: When Alert dialog is visible on an activity i am not getting a call on OnResume() or any other method of Activity lifecycle.